# Out-of-memory-error on Minecraft Server with 16G RAM

Tags: out-of-memory, minecraft, jvm-arguments, jvm-crash

Please excuse my inexperience, this is my first time on the site.
I have a `Dell PowerEdge r710` with 2 `Xeon L5630` CPUs and `16G RAM` installed. I'm trying to host a Minecraft `1.7.10` Forge Server that runs perfectly fine on my Desktop, but refuses to run properly on the server.

This machine is running Java 8, and runs perfectly otherwise. When running the application without the mods, it loads up without a hitch. As I add more mods, it gets worse. As far as my (very, very limited) knowledge goes, the order of JVM arguments doesn't matter, and didn't on my Desktop, but in order to get the application to even run I had to change the order in my .bat file. With all mods installed, the `Out Of Memory` Error occurs with a chunk loading error when around 41% spawn loaded.

This is the .bat file that I've made to start the server:

```
java -jar minecraft_server.jar -Xms512M -Xmx8192M  nogui -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemory
```

This should load up perfectly fine, everything is compatible and tested on another machine, but the exact same setup will not run on the `r710`, saying `Out Of Memory` with more than double the desktop's allocated memory.

Answer (score 1):

First you should use Task Manager or a similar utility to make sure that Java process indeed is using more then the amount you allocated with your arguments. Then I would recommend reading through this lovely post written by `Cpw` and posted on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/feedthebeast/comments/5jhuk9/modded_mc_and_memory_usage_a_history_with_a/?ref=share&ref_source=embed&utm_content=title&utm_medium=post_embed&utm_name=7dbf96da77f54787a9b66da0d094815c&utm_source=embedly&utm_term=5jhuk9). If it doesn't help you with your current situation it should at least give you a bit more information on Minecraft's memory footprint.

In a normal situation where you would be running Minecraft as a local server from your computer I would suggest taking a look at how much memory your `GPU` is taking up. Since you are running a server this is not relevant, but might still be useful to someone who stumbles upon this post so I will leave it here:

> Your graphics card is probably the biggest address hog. Today's graphics adapters often contain a gigabyte or more of RAM, and every one of those bytes needs an address. To be fair, I doubt that many of those multi-gigabyte graphics cards are in 32-bit PCs, but even a 512mb video card will take a sizeable bite out of 4GB.

I am not quite familiar with running dedicated servers but another important thing that is worth mentioning is that in case you are on a `32-bit` operating system you will only be able to take advantage of `4GB` of your `RAM` due to architecture constraints.

> Every byte of RAM requires its own address, and the processor limits the length of those addresses. A 32-bit processor uses addresses that are 32 bits long. There are only 4,294,967,296, or 4GB, possible 32-bit addresses.

If all else fails you should try to seek help on one of the available Discord channels dedicated to Minecraft modding. This should be a rule in general actually, especially for general purpose problems that are difficult for others to reproduce. Here is a small list of three Discord communities dedicated to Minecraft modding that I have experience with:

- [Modded Minecraft](https://discord.gg/moddedmc) - The one with most traffic so it can be a bit more difficult for your question to get noticed on busy days, but definitely the best moderated one from this list.
- [Modding Help](https://discord.gg/Bzx2xq) - The smallest of the three. I don't have much experience with this one.
- [Mod Dev Cafe](http://www.moddevcafe.com/) - This one has a decent size and a pretty good response rate, but be prepared for the usual facepalms and other unpleasantness common to younger admins and moderators. However if you are willing to look past that this is a good choice.